# Regular Expression for one of the use case in java, starting from DANNO and ending with integer

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to create one regex to get a number from string. I used https://regexr.com/ and cam up with the following regex `(DANNO)[^0-9]*[0-9]*` this works fine on their console but when I am trying to use in my java code it's just giving me DANNO for some of the cases.

Some of the sample strings are below with the expected result:

```
N. DANNO: 1234567890 => DANNO: 1234567890
DANNO N° 1234567890 => DANNO N° 1234567890
ORDINE N  1234567890 N  DANNO 1234567890 N  CLIENTE 123456 => DANNO 1234567890
N°DANNO1234567890 => DANNO1234567890
DANNON°1234567890 => DANNON°1234567890
```

Comment: Use: `\bDANNO\D*(\d+)` as regex and grab captured group #1

Comment: @anubhava Amazing, this worked. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {
    final String regex = "(DANNO)[^0-9]*[0-9]*";
    final String string = "N. DANNO: 1234567890\n"
         + "DANNO N° 1234567890\n"
         + "ORDINE N  1234567890 N  DANNO 1234567890 N  CLIENTE 123456\n"
         + "N°DANNO1234567890\n"
         + "DANNON°1234567890";

    final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex, Pattern.MULTILINE);
    final Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(string);

    while (matcher.find()) {
        System.out.println("Full match: " + matcher.group(0)); //Prints full serach result
        for (int i = 1; i <= matcher.groupCount(); i++) {
            System.out.println("Group " + i + ": " + matcher.group(i)); //Prints DANO
        }
    }
}
```

output

```
Full match: DANNO: 1234567890
Group 1: DANNO
Full match: DANNO N° 1234567890
Group 1: DANNO
Full match: DANNO 1234567890
Group 1: DANNO
Full match: DANNO1234567890
Group 1: DANNO
Full match: DANNON°1234567890
Group 1: DANNO
```